# Getting package name from AndroidManifest.xml using SBT and Android Plugin

Tags: scala, package, android-manifest, sbt, sbt-android-plugin

I'm using SBT and modifying Jan Berkel's Android Plugin in and I need the information about the package name of the Android project I'm trying to build.

I know that the package name is located in `AndroidManifest.xml`, but I was wondering if there is any way using SBT to get that package name?

Comment: You need to read this from sbt task or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if that is what you need but anyways. Sbt task are written in scala code, so we can just find that file and then read the content:

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileNotFoundException
def recursiveListFiles(f: File): Array[File] = {
  val these = f.listFiles
  if(these != null) 
    these ++ these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(recursiveListFiles) 
  else Array[File]()
}

val projectFiles = recursiveListFiles(new File("."))
val manifestFile = projectFiles
  .filter(f => f.getCanonicalPath.endsWith("AndroidManifest.xml"))
  .toList.headOption
  .getOrElse(
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Your project doesn't contain manifest")
  )

val manifestXML = scala.xml.XML.loadFile(manifestFile)
val pkg = manifestXML.attribute("package").getOrElse("")
```